# What's the best way to handle Django's objects.get?

Tags: python, django

Whenever I do this:

```
thepost = Content.objects.get(name="test")
```

It always throws an error when nothing is found.
How do I handle it?

Comment: See also [QuerySet.get](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.get)

Comment: That's the way it is supposed to work.  What's your question?  How to write a `try` statement?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
try:
    thepost = Content.objects.get(name="test")
except Content.DoesNotExist:
    thepost = None
```

Use the model DoesNotExist exception

Comment: In this case, the exception is `Content.DoesNotExist`, and this code structure is useful if you want to continue even if the object cannot be found (i.e. not throw a 404 error as in my example).

Answer (score 37):

Often, it is more useful to use the Django shortcut function [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of the API directly:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

thepost = get_object_or_404(Content, name='test')
```

Fairly obviously, this will throw a 404 error if the object cannot be found, and your code will continue if it is successful.

Answer (score 18):

You can also catch a generic DoesNotExist. As per the docs at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    e = Entry.objects.get(id=3)
    b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print "Either the entry or blog doesn't exist."
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way of writing:

```
try:
    thepost = Content.objects.get(name="test")
except Content.DoesNotExist:
    thepost = None
```

is simply:

```
thepost = Content.objects.filter(name="test").first()
```

Note that the two are not strictly the same. Manager method `get` will raise not only an exception in the case **there's no record** you're querying for but also when **multiple records** are found. Using `first` when there are more than one record might fail your business logic silently by returning the first record.

Comment: Just want to chime in - I've found it's almost always better to use `.get` instead of `.first` because as you said it can lead to unexpected results. The only time I use `.first` is if I use a generic foreign key and put validation in place to make sure there's only ever max one item.

Answer (score 8):

Catch the exception

```
try:
    thepost = Content.objects.get(name="test")
except Content.DoesNotExist:
    thepost = None
```

alternatively you can filter, which will return a empty list if nothing matches

```
posts = Content.objects.filter(name="test")
if posts:
    # do something with posts[0] and see if you want to raise error if post > 1
```

Comment: why allocate an empty Queryset when get() will just raise an exception? The try/catch first approach is far better

Comment: Normally, using exceptions for normal 'workflow' is not a good practice. In this example it's fairly easy to understand, but if you start to use exceptions to control an application, it's going to be hard to maintain/debug.

Comment: @mrmuggles I disagree, Exception could be a very good way to structure your code, e..g `for plugin in plugins; try; processed_text = plugin.process(text) ; except Exception1,: do something Exception 2; do something` there is no easier alternate to this, and in this specific case it absolutely makes perfect sense, would you dod dict.has_key before accessing item or just access item and catch KeyError?

Comment: Using exception to structure workflow is an anti-pattern IMO. Here's a discussion about that: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why
Yes, you can save a couple of line of codes, but it doesn't make it a good solution for maintenance. I would check if the item exists, and in fact I would probably wrap this code in a method anyway.

Comment: i think that opinion is not specific to python, I liked the comment on the question 'No. In Python, using exceptions as control flow is considered "pythonic"', python itself uses Exception to tell end of generators etc, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python and http://www.drmaciver.com/2009/03/exceptions-for-control-flow-considered-perfectly-acceptable-thanks-very-much/ , in the end I will say it is moe pythonic, may be not suited for C++ but for python yes.

Comment: @mrmuggles The Python community embraces EAFP, aka Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission.  This style is widely embraced throughout the standard library and the big must-use Python third party libraries.  Here's a random blog post I googled on the subject: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/

Answer (score 4):

Handling exceptions at different points in your views could really be cumbersome..What about defining a custom Model Manager, in the models.py file, like

```
class ContentManager(model.Manager):
    def get_nicely(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get(kwargs)
        except(KeyError, Content.DoesNotExist):
            return None
```

and then including it in the content Model class

```
class Content(model.Model):
    ...
    objects = ContentManager()
```

In this way it can be easily dealt in the views i.e.

```
post = Content.objects.get_nicely(pk = 1)
if post != None:
    # Do something
else:
    # This post doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 4):

There are essentially two ways you can do this. The first approach is more verbose as it doesn't use any `shortcuts`:

```
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Content    


try:
    thepost = Content.objects.get(name="test")
except Content.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Content does not exist")
```

Now since this sort of operation (i.e. get an object or raise 404 if it does not exist) is quite common in Web Development, Django offers a shortcut called [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404) that will `get()` the requested object or raise `Http404` in case it is not found:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Content


thepost = get_object_or_404(Content, name="test")
```

---

Likewise for lists of objects, you can use [`get_list_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.get_list_or_404) function that makes use of `filter()` instead of `get()` and in case the returned list is empty, `Http404` will be raised.

Answer (score 3):

Raising a [Http404 exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) works great:

```
from django.http import Http404

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

Comment: This works only if the Poll object represents the whole view. If you're just trying to query for an object that will land in the middle of a page, you don't want to return 404 for the whole view.