# Is it a good practice to use try-except-else in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

From time to time in Python, I see the block:

```
try:
   try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as exception:
   #Handle exception
else:
   return something
```

**What is the reason for the try-except-else to exist?**

I do not like that kind of programming, as it is using exceptions to perform flow control. However, if it is included in the language, there must be a good reason for it, isn't it?

**It is my understanding that exceptions are not errors**, and that they should only be used for exceptional conditions (e.g. I try to write a file into disk and there is no more space, or maybe I do not have permission), and not for flow control.

Normally I handle exceptions as:

```
something = some_default_value
try:
    something = try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as exception:
    #Handle exception
finally:
    return something
```

Or if I really do not want to return anything if an exception happens, then:

```
try:
    something = try_this(whatever)
    return something
except SomeException as exception:
    #Handle exception
```

Answer (score 856, accepted):

> "I do not know if it is out of ignorance, but I do not like that
>   kind of programming, as it is using exceptions to perform flow control."

In the Python world, using exceptions for flow control is common and normal.

Even the Python core developers use exceptions for flow-control and that style is heavily baked into the language (i.e.  the iterator protocol uses [*StopIteration*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) to signal loop termination).

In addition, the try-except-style is used to prevent the race-conditions inherent in some of the ["look-before-you-leap"](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-lbyl) constructs. For example, testing [*os.path.exists*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) results in information that may be out-of-date by the time you use it.  Likewise, [*Queue.full*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.full) returns information that may be stale.  The [try-except-else style](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) will produce more reliable code in these cases.

> "It my understanding that exceptions are not errors, they should only
>   be used for exceptional conditions"

In some other languages, that rule reflects their cultural norms as reflected in their libraries. The "rule" is also based in-part on performance considerations for those languages.

The Python cultural norm is somewhat different. In many cases, you *must* use exceptions for control-flow. Also, the use of exceptions in Python does not slow the surrounding code and calling code as it does in some compiled languages (i.e. [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) already implements code for exception checking at every step, regardless of whether you actually use exceptions or not).

In other words, your understanding that "exceptions are for the exceptional" is a rule that makes sense in some other languages, but not for Python.

> "However, if it is included in the language itself, there must be a
>   good reason for it, isn't it?"

Besides helping to avoid race-conditions, exceptions are also very useful for pulling error-handling outside loops. This is a necessary optimization in interpreted languages which do not tend to have automatic [loop invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion).

Also, exceptions can simplify code quite a bit in common situations where the ability to handle an issue is far removed from where the issue arose. For example, it is common to have top level user-interface code calling code for business logic which in turn calls low-level routines. Situations arising in the low-level routines (such as duplicate records for unique keys in database accesses) can only be handled in top-level code (such as asking the user for a new key that doesn't conflict with existing keys).  The use of exceptions for this kind of control-flow allows the mid-level routines to completely ignore the issue and be nicely decoupled from that aspect of flow-control.

There is a [nice blog post on the indispensibility of exceptions here](http://uberpython.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/why-im-not-leaving-python-for-go/).

Also, see this Stack Overflow answer: [Are exceptions really for exceptional errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180937/are-exceptions-really-for-exceptional-errors)

> "What is the reason for the try-except-else to exist?"

The else-clause itself is interesting. It runs when there is no exception but before the finally-clause. That is its primary purpose.

Without the else-clause, the only option to run additional code before finalization would be the clumsy practice of adding the code to the try-clause. That is clumsy because it risks
raising exceptions in code that wasn't intended to be protected by the try-block.

The use-case of running additional unprotected code prior to finalization doesn't arise very often. So, don't expect to see many examples in published code. It is somewhat rare.

Another use-case for the else-clause is to perform actions that must occur when no exception occurs and that do not occur when exceptions are handled. For example:

```py
recip = float('Inf')
try:
    recip = 1 / f(x)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    logging.info('Infinite result')
else:
    logging.info('Finite result')
```

Another example occurs in unittest runners:

```
try:
    tests_run += 1
    run_testcase(case)
except Exception:
    tests_failed += 1
    logging.exception('Failing test case: %r', case)
    print('F', end='')
else:
    logging.info('Successful test case: %r', case)
    print('.', end='')
```

Lastly, the most common use of an else-clause in a try-block is for a bit of beautification (aligning the exceptional outcomes and non-exceptional outcomes at the same level of indentation). This use is always optional and isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: "That is clumsy because it risks raising exceptions in code that wasn't intended to be protected by the try-block." This is the most important learning here

Comment: `In the Python world, using exceptions for flow control is common and normal.` -- I think it's worth drawing a distinction between "the Python world" and "the CPython core devs world".  I've worked on a lot of Python codebases and rarely see exceptions used for flow control, and have seen many Python developers discourage that use.

Comment: "Another use-case for the else-clause is to perform actions that must occur when no exception occurs and that do not occur when exceptions are handled." That helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO Adam's comment doesn't match reality.  Every single time you use a for-loop, the StopIteration exception is used for control flow.  When you run an index() Sequence method in a loop, you catch ValueError to end the loop.  Whenever you use the recommended EAPF style for atomicity, you're using exceptions for control flow.   It is heavily baked into the language.  Really, the only thing to be discouraged is using exceptions when there is a simpler alternative, such as a `break` or `return`.

Comment: In each example, I don't know why the contents of the `else` block isn't just at the end of the `try` block.

Answer (score 214):

> ### What is the reason for the try-except-else to exist?

A `try` block allows you to handle an expected error. The `except` block should only catch exceptions you are prepared to handle. If you handle an unexpected error, your code may do the wrong thing and hide bugs.

An `else` clause will execute if there were no errors, and by not executing that code in the `try` block, you avoid catching an unexpected error. Again, catching an unexpected error can hide bugs.

#### Example

For example:

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
else:
    return something
```

The "try, except" suite has two optional clauses, `else` and `finally`. So it's actually `try-except-else-finally`.

`else` will evaluate only if there is no exception from the `try` block. It allows us to simplify the more complicated code below:

```
no_error = None
try:
    try_this(whatever)
    no_error = True
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
if no_error:
    return something
```

so if we compare an `else` to the alternative (which might create bugs) we see that it reduces the lines of code and we can have a more readable, maintainable, and less buggy code-base.

#### `finally`

`finally` will execute no matter what, even if another line is being evaluated with a return statement.

### Broken down with pseudo-code

It might help to break this down, in the smallest possible form that demonstrates all features, with comments. Assume this syntactically correct (but not runnable unless the names are defined) pseudo-code is in a function.

For example:

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle_SomeException(the_exception)
    # Handle a instance of SomeException or a subclass of it.
except Exception as the_exception:
    generic_handle(the_exception)
    # Handle any other exception that inherits from Exception
    # - doesn't include GeneratorExit, KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit
    # Avoid bare `except:`
else: # there was no exception whatsoever
    return something()
    # if no exception, the "something()" gets evaluated,
    # but the return will not be executed due to the return in the
    # finally block below.
finally:
    # this block will execute no matter what, even if no exception,
    # after "something" is eval'd but before that value is returned
    # but even if there is an exception.
    # a return here will hijack the return functionality. e.g.:
    return True # hijacks the return in the else clause above
```

It is true that we *could* include the code in the `else` block in the `try` block instead, where it would run if there were no exceptions, but what if that code itself raises an exception of the kind we're catching? Leaving it in the `try` block would hide that bug.

We want to minimize lines of code in the `try` block to avoid catching exceptions we did not expect, under the principle that if our code fails, we want it to fail loudly. This is a [best practice](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html).

> ### It is my understanding that exceptions are not errors

In Python, most exceptions are errors.

We can view the exception hierarchy by using pydoc. For example, in Python 2:

```
$ python -m pydoc exceptions
```

or Python 3:

```
$ python -m pydoc builtins
```

Will give us the hierarchy. We can see that most kinds of `Exception` are errors, although Python uses some of them for things like ending `for` loops (`StopIteration`). This is Python 3's hierarchy:

```
BaseException
    Exception
        ArithmeticError
            FloatingPointError
            OverflowError
            ZeroDivisionError
        AssertionError
        AttributeError
        BufferError
        EOFError
        ImportError
            ModuleNotFoundError
        LookupError
            IndexError
            KeyError
        MemoryError
        NameError
            UnboundLocalError
        OSError
            BlockingIOError
            ChildProcessError
            ConnectionError
                BrokenPipeError
                ConnectionAbortedError
                ConnectionRefusedError
                ConnectionResetError
            FileExistsError
            FileNotFoundError
            InterruptedError
            IsADirectoryError
            NotADirectoryError
            PermissionError
            ProcessLookupError
            TimeoutError
        ReferenceError
        RuntimeError
            NotImplementedError
            RecursionError
        StopAsyncIteration
        StopIteration
        SyntaxError
            IndentationError
                TabError
        SystemError
        TypeError
        ValueError
            UnicodeError
                UnicodeDecodeError
                UnicodeEncodeError
                UnicodeTranslateError
        Warning
            BytesWarning
            DeprecationWarning
            FutureWarning
            ImportWarning
            PendingDeprecationWarning
            ResourceWarning
            RuntimeWarning
            SyntaxWarning
            UnicodeWarning
            UserWarning
    GeneratorExit
    KeyboardInterrupt
    SystemExit
```

A commenter asked:

> Say you have a method which pings an external API and you want to handle the exception at a class outside the API wrapper, do you simply return e from the method under the except clause where e is the exception object?

No, you don't return the exception, just reraise it with a bare `raise` to preserve the stacktrace.

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
    raise
```

Or, in Python 3, you can raise a new exception and preserve the backtrace with exception chaining:

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
    raise DifferentException from the_exception
```

I elaborate in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python).

Comment: upvoted! what do you usually do inside the handle part? lets say you have a method which pings an external API and you want to handle the exception at a class outside the API wrapper, do you simply return e from the method under the except clause where e is the exception object?

Comment: @PirateApp thank you! no, don't return it, you should probably reraise with a bare `raise` or do exception chaining - but that's more on topic and covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2052390/541136 - I'll probably remove these comments after I've seen you've seen them.

Comment: thank you so much for the details! going through the post now

Answer (score 51):

Python doesn't subscribe to the idea that exceptions should only be used for exceptional cases, in fact the idiom is ['ask for forgiveness, not permission'](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). This means that using exceptions as a routine part of your flow control is perfectly acceptable, and in fact, encouraged.

This is generally a good thing, as working this way helps avoid some issues (as an obvious example, race conditions are often avoided), and it tends to make code a little more readable.

Imagine you have a situation where you take some user input which needs to be processed, but have a default which is already processed. The `try: ... except: ... else: ...` structure makes for very readable code:

```
try:
   raw_value = int(input())
except ValueError:
   value = some_processed_value
else: # no error occured
   value = process_value(raw_value)
```

Compare to how it might work in other languages:

```
raw_value = input()
if valid_number(raw_value):
    value = process_value(int(raw_value))
else:
    value = some_processed_value
```

Note the advantages. There is no need to check the value is valid and parse it separately, they are done once. The code also follows a more logical progression, the main code path is first, followed by 'if it doesn't work, do this'.

The example is naturally a little contrived, but it shows there are cases for this structure.

Answer (score 25):

See the following example which illustrate everything about try-except-else-finally:

```
for i in range(3):
    try:
        y = 1 / i
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print(f"\ti = {i}")
        print("\tError report: ZeroDivisionError")
    else:
        print(f"\ti = {i}")
        print(f"\tNo error report and y equals {y}")
    finally:
        print("Try block is run.")
```

Implement it and come by:

```
    i = 0
    Error report: ZeroDivisionError
Try block is run.
    i = 1
    No error report and y equals 1.0
Try block is run.
    i = 2
    No error report and y equals 0.5
Try block is run.
```

Comment: This is a great, simple example that _quickly_ demonstrates the full **try** clause without requiring someone (who may be in quite a hurry) to read a lengthy abstract explanation. (Of course, when they're not in a hurry anymore, they should come back and read the full abstract.)

Answer (score 17):

> **Is it a good practice to use try-except-else in python?**

The answer to this is that it is context dependent. If you do this:

```
d = dict()
try:
    item = d['item']
except KeyError:
    item = 'default'
```

It demonstrates that you don't know Python very well. This functionality is encapsulated in the `dict.get` method:

```
item = d.get('item', 'default')
```

The `try`/`except` block is a much more visually cluttered and verbose way of writing what can be efficiently executing in a single line with an atomic method. There are other cases where this is true.

However, that does not mean that we should avoid all exception handling. In some cases it is preferred to avoid race conditions. Don't check if a file exists, just attempt to open it, and catch the appropriate IOError. For the sake of simplicity and readability, try to encapsulate this or factor it out as apropos.

Read the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), understanding that there are principles that are in tension, and be wary of dogma that relies too heavily on any one of the statements in it.

Answer (score 8):

You should be careful about using the finally block, as it is not the same thing as using an else block in the try, except. The finally block will be run regardless of the outcome of the try except.

```
In [10]: dict_ = {"a": 1}

In [11]: try:
   ....:     dict_["b"]
   ....: except KeyError:
   ....:     pass
   ....: finally:
   ....:     print "something"
   ....:     
something
```

As everyone has noted using the else block causes your code to be more readable, and only runs when an exception is not thrown

```
In [14]: try:
             dict_["b"]
         except KeyError:
             pass
         else:
             print "something"
   ....:
```

Comment: I know that finally is always executed, and that is why it can be used to our advantage by always setting a default value, so in case of exception it is returned, if we do not want to return such value in case of exception, it is enough to remove the final block. Btw, using pass on an exception catch is something I would never ever do :)

Comment: @Juan Antonio Gomez Moriano , my coding block is for example purposes only. I probably would never use pass either

Answer (score 8):

Just because no-one else has posted this opinion, I would say

> avoid `else` clauses in `try/excepts` *because they're unfamiliar to most people*

Unlike the keywords `try`, `except`, and `finally`, the meaning of the `else` clause isn't self-evident; it's less readable. Because it's not used very often, it'll cause people that read your code to want to double-check the docs to be sure they understand what's going on.

(I'm writing this answer precisely because I found a `try/except/else` in my codebase and it caused a wtf moment and forced me to do some googling).

So, wherever I see code like the OP example:

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
else:
    # do some more processing in non-exception case
    return something
```

I would prefer to refactor to

```
try:
    try_this(whatever)
except SomeException as the_exception:
    handle(the_exception)
    return  # <1>
# do some more processing in non-exception case  <2>
return something
```

- <1> explicit return, clearly shows that, in the exception case, we are finished working
- <2> as a nice minor side-effect, the code that used to be in the `else` block is dedented by one level.

Comment: Devil's argument counter-argument: the more people use it, the more well-adopted it will become. Just food for thought, though I do agree that readability is import. That said, once someone understands try-else, I would argue that it's much more readable than the alternative in many cases.

Comment: I'm rarely convinced by any argument for second-guessing oneself based on what "most people" might/might not know. I'm also highly suspicious of arguments for catering to ignorance.   `try`-`else` is a Python-specific construct not found in C/C++/Java. For one particular construct of "most people", most people program Python as if it's C/C++/Java, not taking advantage of many of the unique features that make Python elegant and powerful. Therefore we should use an unwieldy/inefficient subset of Python to cater to them? List-comprehensions also seem to attract this argument.  I do not buy it.

Comment: if they are using Python and don't know else probably need to to study properly (not random tutorials), in case you're working and are junior you'll have seniors to ask or SO

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you see this:

```
try:
    y = 1 / x
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
else:
    return y
```

Or even this:

```
try:
    return 1 / x
except ZeroDivisionError:
    return None
```

Consider this instead:

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.suppress(ZeroDivisionError):
    return 1 / x
```

Comment: It does not answer my question, as that was simply an example my friend.

Comment: In Python, exceptions are not errors.  They're not even exceptional.  In Python, it's normal and natural to use exceptions for flow control.  This is evidenced by the inclusion of contextlib.suppress() in the standard library.  See Raymond Hettinger's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16138864/1197429 (Raymond is a core Python contributor, and an authority on all things Pythonic!)

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple snippet on howto understand try-except-else-finally block in Python:

```
def div(a, b):
    try:
        a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Zero Division Error detected")
    else:
        print("No Zero Division Error")
    finally:
        print("Finally the division of %d/%d is done" % (a, b))
```

Let's try div 1/1:

```
div(1, 1)
No Zero Division Error
Finally the division of 1/1 is done
```

Let's try div 1/0

```
div(1, 0)
Zero Division Error detected
Finally the division of 1/0 is done
```

Comment: I think this fails to exemplify why you can't just put the else code inside the try

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to answer this question in a slightly different angle.

There were 2 parts of the OP's question, and I add the 3rd one, too.

1. What is the reason for the try-except-else to exist?
2. Does the try-except-else pattern, or the Python in general, encourage using exceptions for flow control?
3. When to use exceptions, anyway?

#### Question 1: What is the reason for the try-except-else to exist?

It can be answered from a tactical standpoint. There is of course reason for `try...except...` to exist. The only new addition here is the `else...` clause, whose usefulness boils down to its uniqueness:

- It runs an extra code block ONLY WHEN there was no exception happened in the `try...` block.
- It runs that extra code block, OUTSIDE of the `try...` block (meaning any potential exceptions happen inside the `else...` block would NOT be caught).
- It runs that extra code block BEFORE the `final...` finalization.

  ```py
    db = open(...)
    try:
        db.insert(something)
    except Exception:
        db.rollback()
        logging.exception('Failing: %s, db is ROLLED BACK', something)
    else:
        db.commit()
        logging.info(
            'Successful: %d',  # <-- For the sake of demonstration,
                               # there is a typo %d here to trigger an exception.
                               # If you move this section into the try... block,
                               # the flow would unnecessarily go to the rollback path.
            something)
    finally:
        db.close()
  ```

  In the example above, you can't move that successful log line into behind the `finally...` block. You can't quite move it into inside the `try...` block, either, due to the potential exception inside the `else...` block.

#### Question 2: does Python encourage using exceptions for flow control?

I found no official written documentation to support that claim. (To readers who would disagree: please leave comments with links to evidences you found.) The only vaguely-relevant paragraph that I found, is this [EAFP term](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

> EAFP
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

Such paragraph merely described that, rather than doing this:

```py
def make_some_noise(speaker):
    if hasattr(speaker, "quack"):
        speaker.quack()
```

we would prefer this:

```py
def make_some_noise(speaker):
    try:
        speaker.quack()
    except AttributeError:
        logger.warning("This speaker is not a duck")

make_some_noise(DonaldDuck())  # This would work
make_some_noise(DonaldTrump())  # This would trigger exception
```

or potentially even omitting the try...except:

```py
def make_some_noise(duck):
    duck.quack()
```

So, the EAFP encourages duck-typing. But it does not encourage using exceptions *for flow control*.

#### Question 3: In what situation you should design your program to *emit* exceptions?

It is a moot conversation on whether it is anti-pattern to *use* exception as control flow. Because, once a design decision is made for a given function, its usage pattern would also be determined, and then the caller would have no choice but to use it that way.

So, let's go back to the fundamentals to see when a function would better produce its outcome via returning a value or via emitting exception(s).

What is the difference between the return value and the exception?

1. Their "blast radius" are different. Return value is only available to the immediate caller; exception can be automatically relayed for unlimited distance until it is caught.
2. Their distribution patterns are different. Return value is by definition one piece of data (even though you could return a compound data type such as a dictionary or a container object, it is still technically one value).
   The exception mechanism, on the contrary, allows multiple values (one at a time) to be returned via their respective dedicate channel. Here, each `except FooError: ...` and `except BarError: ...` block is considered as its own dedicate channel.

Therefore, it is up to each different scenario to use one mechanism that fits well.

- All normal cases should better be returned via return value, because the callers would most likely need to use that return value immediately. The return-value approach also allows nesting layers of callers in a functional programming style. The exception mechanism's long blast radius and multiple channels do not help here.
  For example, it would be unintuitive if any function named `get_something(...)` produces its happy path result as an exception. (This is not really a contrived example. There is [one practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351110/are-exceptions-for-flow-control-best-practice-in-python) to implement `BinaryTree.Search(value)` to use exception to ship the value back in the middle of a deep recursion.)
- If the caller would likely forget to handle the error sentinel from the return value, it is probably a good idea to use exception's characterist #2 to save caller from its hidden bug. A typical non-example would be the `position = find_string(haystack, needle)`, unfortunately its return value of `-1` or `null` would tend to cause a bug in the caller.
- If the error sentinel would collide with a normal value in the result namespace, it is almost certain to use an exception, because you'd have to use a different channel to convey that error.
- If the normal channel i.e. the return value is already used in the happy-path, AND the happy-path does NOT have sophisicated flow control, you have no choice but to use exception for flow control. People keep talking about how Python uses `StopIteration` exception for iteration termination, and use it to kind of justify "using exception for flow control". But IMHO this is only a practical choice in a particular situation, it does not generalize and glorify "using exception for flow control".

At this point, if you already make a sound decision on whether your function `get_stock_price()` would produce only return-value or also raise exceptions, or if that function is provided by an existing library so that its behavior has long be decided, you do not have much choice in writing its caller `calculate_market_trend()`. Whether to use `get_stock_price()`'s exception to control the flow in your `calculate_market_trend()` is merely a matter of whether your business logic requires you to do so. If yes, do it; otherwise, let the exception bubble up to a higher level (this utilizes the characteristic #1 "long blast radius" of exception).

In particular, if you are implementing a middle-layer library `Foo` and you happen to be making a dependency on lower-level library `Bar`, you would probably want to hide your implementation detail, by catching all `Bar.ThisError`, `Bar.ThatError`, ..., and map them into `Foo.GenericError`. In this case, the long blast radius is actually working against us, so you might hope "only if library Bar were returning its errors via return values". But then again, that decision has long been made in `Bar`, so you can just live with it.

All in all, I think whether to *use* exception as control flow is a moot point.

Answer (score -2):

OP, YOU ARE CORRECT.  **The else after try/except in Python is ugly**.  it leads to another flow-control object where none is needed:

```
try:
    x = blah()
except:
    print "failed at blah()"
else:
    print "just succeeded with blah"
```

A totally clear equivalent is:

```
try:
    x = blah()
    print "just succeeded with blah"
except:
    print "failed at blah()"
```

This is far clearer than an else clause.  The else after try/except is not frequently written, so it takes a moment to figure what the implications are.

**Just because you CAN do a thing, doesn't mean you SHOULD do a thing.**

Lots of features have been added to languages because someone thought it might come in handy.  Trouble is, the more features, the less clear and obvious things are because people don't usually use those bells and whistles.

Just my 5 cents here.  I have to come along behind and clean up a lot of code written by 1st-year out of college developers who think they're smart and want to write code in some uber-tight, uber-efficient way when that just makes it a mess to try and read / modify later.  I vote for readability every day and twice on Sundays.

Comment: You're right.  That's totally clear and equivalent...unless it's your `print` statement that fails.  What happens if `x = blah()` returns a `str`, but your print statement is `print 'just succeeded with blah. x == %d' % x`?  Now you've got a `TypeError` being generated where you're not prepared to handle one; you're inspecting `x = blah()` to find the source of the exception, and it's not even there.  I've done this (or the equivalent) more than once where the `else` would've kept me from making this mistake.  Now I know better. :-D

Comment: ...and yes, you're right.  The `else` clause isn't a pretty statement, and until you're used to it, it's not intuitive.  But then, neither was `finally` when I first started using it...

Comment: To echo Doug R., it *isn't* equivalent because exceptions during the statements in the `else` clause are *not* caught by the `except`.

Comment: if...except...else is more readable, otherwise you have to read "oh, after try block, and no exception, go to statement outside the try block", so  using else: tends to semantically connect the syntax a bit better imo. Also, it's good practice to leave your untrapped statements outside of the initial try block.

Comment: finally is for cleanup/housekeeping code (code that is executed regardless of whether the try threw an exception or not). Using this appropriately is also useful lend more semantic meaning to your code, instead of leaving "naked" always-executing-statements outside of the exception handling block.

Comment: This post was helpful in explaining the necessity of the else clause in the try-except-else block: http://shahriar.svbtle.com/the-possibly-forgotten-optional-else-in-python-try-statement

Comment: @DougR. "you're inspecting `x = blah()` to find the source of the exception", Having `traceback` why would you inspect the exception source from a wrong place?

Comment: According to the official docs, the reason for else is "The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception...(EXAMPLE SKIPPED)... 
The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try … except statement."