# Is it possible to return from an outer function from within an inner function?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I would like to jump out of an outer function from inside an inner function.

```
something = true

outer: (next)-> 
    @inner (err)-> 
        if err?
            next err 
            #jump out of outer function here

    console.log 'still in outer'

inner: (next)-> 
    next new Error 'oops' if @something is true
```

The code is in coffeescript but javascript answers are welcome.

**Update**

Thanks for the quick replies - so how about using the return value of the `@inner` function? Is there a generally accepted pattern for this kind of thing?

```
something = true

outer: (next)-> 
    return unless @inner (err)-> next err if err
    console.log 'still in outer'

inner: (next)-> 
    if @something is true
        next new Error 'oops'
        return false
    return true
```

Comment: You will need to have one bool variable & while returning from inner function set that variable & in outer function check it's value,if it;s set as true then return from outer as well.

Comment: You could just `throw` of course…

Comment: @Bergi: :-) Yes. But we don't use exceptions for normal program flow, right? *Right?* ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That depends on the language paradigm (I'm a bit pythonic) and of course whether the OP's reason to jump out actually is exceptional :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Your second point is very well made indeed. :-) Python uses exceptions for normal flow?

Comment: @biofractal: Yes, the return value is the usual way to do this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: [More or less, yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16138864/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *reason* you want to immediately exit `outer` is that an *exceptional condition* occurred (an error), you can throw an exception. If `outer` doesn't catch it, `outer` will be terminated (as will `outer`'s caller, and so on, until something either catches the exception or the JS engine itself does).

For *normal* program flow, though, in JavaScript and the various languages that transpile into it, we don't use exceptions for normal program flow (not least because they're expensive). For those cases, no, there's no way for a called function to terminate its caller; it has to either return a value that caller uses to know to exit, or set a value on a variable that's in scope for both of them.

Here's your example updated to use `inner`'s return value, which would be the most normal way to do this:

```
something = true

outer: (next)-> 
    stop = @inner (err)-> 
        if err?
            next err 
            #jump out of outer function here

    if stop
      return
    console.log 'still in outer'

inner: (next)-> 
    next new Error 'oops' if @something is true
    if someCondition
      return true
```

Here's your example updated to use a variable they both close over:

```
something = true

stop = false

outer: (next)-> 
    @inner (err)-> 
        if err?
            next err 
            #jump out of outer function here

    if stop
      return
    console.log 'still in outer'

inner: (next)-> 
    next new Error 'oops' if @something is true
    if someCondition
      stop = true
```

*(Please excuse my CoffeeScript, I don't use it.)*

Comment: Where is the value of the `stop` flag being set in your examples?

Comment: @biofractal: Er, um...I seem to have forgotten that bit in my struggles with CoffeeScript. My *first* example, which I made up entirely (this was before your updated code) had it! :-) Let's see, one sec...

Comment: Great, thanks. And look, I have got you writing CoffeeScript at last. They said it would never happen :-)

Comment: @biofractal: :-D I *do* feel a strong need to go wash my hands now... ;-) *(Just a joke. I think the proliferation of languages that transpile to JS is a good thing.)*

Comment: evidence that the claim "exceptions are expensive" is false: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089089/returning-from-outer-function-inside-nested-function-using-throw/63144123#63144123

Comment: @mathheadinclouds - Throwing *errors* used to be much more expensive than it is now (but it's still expensive on some engines). Throwing non-errors isn't, particularly (no need to collect stack information), which is why I never claimed it was when answering your question. I think we've said all that needs saying to each other on this, let's just leave it there, thank you. You want to use `throw` for mainline execution? Knock yourself out, it's *your* code.