# How can I use pytest.raises with multiple exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pytest, contextmanager

I'm testing code where one of two exceptions can be raised: [MachineError](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions/) or NotImplementedError. I would like to use `pytest.raises` to make sure that at least one of them is raised when I run my test code, but it only seems to accept one exception type as an argument.

This is the signature for `pytest.raises`:

```
raises(expected_exception, *args, **kwargs)
```

I tried using the `or` keyword inside a context manager:

```
with pytest.raises(MachineError) or pytest.raises(NotImplementedError):
    verb = Verb("donner<IND><FUT><REL><SG><1>")
    verb.conjugate()
```

but I assume this only checks whether the first `pytest.raises` is `None` and sets the second one as the context manager if it is.

Passing multiple exceptions as positional arguments doesn't work, because `pytest.raises` takes its second argument to be a callable. Every subsequent positional argument is passed as an argument to that callable.

From the [documentation](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html):

```
>>> raises(ZeroDivisionError, lambda: 1/0)
<ExceptionInfo ...>

>>> def f(x): return 1/x
...
>>> raises(ZeroDivisionError, f, 0)
<ExceptionInfo ...>
>>> raises(ZeroDivisionError, f, x=0)
<ExceptionInfo ...>
```

Passing the exceptions as a list doesn't work either:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    with pytest.raises([MachineError, NotImplementedError]):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1290, in raises
    raise TypeError(msg % type(expected_exception))
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not <class 'list'>
```

Is there a workaround for this? It doesn't have to use a context manager.

Comment: Did you try passing multiple exceptions to raises, either as positional arguments or a tuple?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried passing multiple exceptions with a list, not a tuple. [cxw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403866/2202669) works.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Pass the exceptions as a tuple to `raises`:

```
with pytest.raises( (MachineError, NotImplementedError) ):
    verb = ...
```

In the source for `pytest`, `pytest.raises` may:

- [catch `expected_exception`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3155d0ca9c75d3c984de84251ff12d97253134f3/_pytest/python.py#L1306); or
- [pass `expected_exception` to a `RaisesContext` instance](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3155d0ca9c75d3c984de84251ff12d97253134f3/_pytest/python.py#L1293), which then [uses `issubclass`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3155d0ca9c75d3c984de84251ff12d97253134f3/_pytest/python.py#L1337) to check whether the exception was one you wanted.

In Python 3, [`except` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) can take a tuple of exceptions.  The `issubclass` function [can also take a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass).  Therefore, using a tuple should be acceptable in either situation.

Comment: Any idea why exceptions can be passed as a tuple but not a list? I read the docs but I don't understand why lists aren't allowed even though they're iterable.

Comment: @fenceop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851782/why-does-handling-multiple-exceptions-require-a-tuple-and-not-a-list

Comment: Although in general from a test perspective, I think this should be disallowed. It's almost like saying:
assert 1 + 2 == 3 or 4

Comment: @JonathanNazario: Disagree. Sometimes it is better to tell in the tests what you really want, not what you implemented. If you are fine with both errors to be raised (e.g. because it just depends on the implementation order), you should not implement a stricter test just by knowing the implementation. This is equivalently true for values. If you just require the function returns any element from a set of candidates, do not check against one specific element.