# Difference between expect without specifier vs else?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

In Python's `try`, `except` blocks, why does `else` need to exist if I can just use an `except:` without a specifier?

Comment: Have you tried the second one?

Comment: Go through this below link. Nicely explained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your understanding of how `try`, `except`, `else`, and `finally` is off.

Here's a summary of how they all work together, from looking at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html:

```
try:
    #Try something that might raise an exception
except <exception specifier>:
    #Code here will only run if the exception that came up was the one specified
except:
    #Except clause without specifier will catch all exceptions
else:
    #Executed if try clause doesn't raise exception
    #You can only have this else here if you also have except blocks
finally:
    #Runs no matter what
```