# Python OpenCV Error: "TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float"

Tags: python, opencv

So I am trying to create a Python Program to detect similar details in two images using Python's OpenCV.  I have the two images and they are in my current directory, and they exist (see the code in lines 6-17).  But I am getting the following error when I try running it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

path1 = "WIN_20171207_13_51_33_Pro.jpg"
path2 = "WIN_20171207_13_51_43_Pro.jpg"

if os.path.isfile(path1):
    img1 = cv2.imread('WIN_20171207_13_51_33_Pro.jpeg',0)
else:
    print ("The file " + path1 + " does not exist.")

if os.path.isfile(path2):
    img2 = cv2.imread('WIN_20171207_13_51_43_Pro.jpeg',0)
else:
    print ("The file " + path2 + " does not exist.")

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kpl1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kpl2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kpl1,img2,kpl2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)

plt.imshow (img3)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error I keep on getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\jweir\source\repos\BruteForceFeatureDetection\BruteForceFeatureDetection\BruteForceFeatureDetection.py", line 31, in <module>
    plt.imshow (img3)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3080, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1710, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5194, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 600, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

Can someone please explpain to me why I am getting this error, what it means, and how to fix it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, so I deleted my answer that I believed was the cause. Why is it that you check `isfile(path1)` and then you don't actually read `path1`? The extension is different on the images, why is that? What version of mpl are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not actually reading in an image.

Check out what happens if you try to display `None` in matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(None)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>
>  File ".../example.py", line 16, in <module>  
>    plt.imshow(None)  
>  File ".../matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3157, in imshow  
>    **kwargs)  
>  File ".../matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner  
>    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)  
>  File ".../matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5124, in imshow  
>    im.set_data(X)  
>  File ".../matplotlib/image.py", line 596, in set_data  
>    raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")  
>
> TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
> ```

You're reading `WIN_20171207_13_51_33_Pro.jpeg` but you're checking if `WIN_20171207_13_51_33_Pro.jpg` exists. Note the different extensions. Why do you have the filename written twice (and differently)? Just simply write:

```
if os.path.isfile(path1):
    img1 = cv2.imread(path1, 0)
else:
    print ("The file " + path1 + " does not exist.")
```

Note that even if you put a bogus file into `cv2.imread()`, the resulting image will just be `None`, which doesn't error in any of the subsequent function calls until matplotlib tries to draw it. If you `print(img1)` after reading, you'll see it's `None` and not reading properly.

Comment: Good catch, You probably should report this on opencv-python. +1

Comment: @user1767754 what do you mean? `opencv-python` is a pip package, but regardless, this isn't anything wrong with `OpenCV` (or `matplotlib`, which is the library issuing the exception here), it's user error. Python's model of execution is specifically to not check types, lengths, and so on and just *try* to do what the user wants. IMO this `matplotlib` error is very consistent with how Python is generally implemented. For e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16138864/5087436) excellent answer on Stack discussing exceptions in Python.

Comment: Code should be hard to break and easy to debug. When Code fails, it should give a good hint what went wrong, which isn't happening in OpenCV's case. I'm not saying that it isn't a user error, but the error is misleading.  Pythons open method `f = open('blub', 'r')` checks for existence as well.

Comment: @user1767754 So you are saying that you think `cv2.imread('some_bogus_file.ext')` should error instead of returning `None`? That's something you can take up with the authors on a GitHub issue, but it is intended behavior. From the [docs for `imread()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) "The function `imread` loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix (`Mat::data==NULL`)."

Comment: You are citing the C++ Docs, it is a common practice to return a `null pointer` when a process fails in C/C++.  It is common practice too, to throw exceptions early when in this example the file is read, as you can react sooner. Either OpenCV doesn't handle `open` Exceptions at all or it is not properly propagating them.

Comment: @user1767754 and it's common in the OpenCV Python bindings to return `None` in those cases. I'm not trying to argue for/against either cause here but OpenCV is a C++ library, and when you call a function it passes through to the C++ functions. You should not expect Python errors to propagate through when these are just bindings to a library in another language. OpenCV chooses to *not* give an error when reading a file that doesn't exist as the documentation shows---again, if you want to raise that as an issue on their GitHub, feel free, but idk why we're talking about it, I didn't write it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether it is relevant with your case but since we assigning the file path in string type like `cv2.imread("filepathHere")`, if arguments like "\b" or "\r" occurs in the file path it causes program to pop an error such as this.

When I encountered such an error before, I changed the file name from file / brick.png to ibrick.png and the problem was resolved.