# Colab doesn't work. TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python

I am trying to display an image through imshow function in colab. It is giving me the typeerror. I have also tried to display it through cv2. Still no luck! :(

```
# Load in Grayscale
img = cv2.imread('stairs.jpg', 0)

# The underlying representation is a numpy array!
print(type(img))

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704895/python-opencv-error-typeerror-image-data-cannot-be-converted-to-float/47705481)  answer. Figured out that the colab don't access files from within the ColabNotebooks(where my image was actually present), so there was no image being passed to the imshow function causing this error. 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently the colab kernal doesn't play nice when displaying images. Found this code though that uses matplotlib instead. Hope it helps.

%matplotlib inline

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
```

Load in Grayscale

```
img = cv2.imread('./dt.jpg', 0)
```

The underlying representation is a numpy array!

```
print(type(img))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
img = cv2.imread('./dt.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

This would work normally, but it will crash the colab kernel, so don't.

```
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
```