# BadStatusLine('\x00\x06\x83\x88 HTTP/1.0 200 Ok\r\n',))

Tags: python, urllib, status

I'm sending an HTTP request using Python 3's urllib and am receiving a bad status line exception.

Code:

```
mote_file = six.moves.urllib.request.urlopen(scan_uri)
```

Error message:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x06\x87\x1aHTTP/1.0 200 Ok\r\n',))

The request was made successfully but I am getting an exception because of the special characters.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or suppress the exception?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python to see how to handle an exception in Python. For your code, the python doc for urlopen will lead you to the specific exception to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for my scenario.

In C:\Python36\lib\http\client.py, I added

`if not line.startswith("HTTP/"): line = line[4:]`

before

`try: version, status, reason = line.split(None, 2)`

in _read_status(self) function.

It removes the four characters before checking if the status is a valid one.