# Need a try catch block

Tags: python, try-catch

The function below works fine except if it scans the page and finds the tag "fullview-news-outer" does not exists. This produces the error **"list index out of range"**. How can I do a try catch to make sure tag "fullview-news-outer" exists and if it does not exit else set the table variable accordingly.

```
def get_news2(ticker):
    """
    Returns a list of sets containing news headline and url
    """
    page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=STOCK_URL, payload={'t': ticker}, parse=True)
    table = page_parsed.cssselect('table[class="fullview-news-outer"]')[0]
    ...
    return (df)
```

Comment: Don't use `try/catch`. Put the result of `cssselect()` in a variable, and check the length.

Comment: `try: ... except IndexError: ...`…?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to use try-except-else in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python)

Comment: Yes, thank you new to site. Just wanted to know what the -1 means for my question. Thank you. Your Idea worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as barmar said

```
table = page_parsed.cssselect('table[class="fullview-news-outer"]')
 if len(table) > 0:
      tbl_first = table[0]
```

Comment: Yes Barmar. I used something very similar to your code. As for the try catch block i was using it as an idea i knew I had to but some logic in place to account for missing/bad data. Thank you for the correction however will remember that going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem without try-catch

```
page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=STOCK_URL, payload={'t': ticker}, parse=True) 
selected = page_parsed.cssselect('table[class="fullview-news-outer"]')
if selected:
    table = selected[0]
```