# Create a function that loops through a nested list and return a dictionary: Empty elements in list return a none in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists, is-empty

I am using **Python 3**. I need to **create a function**: `contacts()` that **loops through a nested list and returns a dictionary** of an item for each contact name and area-code. If the data does not include area code (**empty element**) then the value **should be `None`**.

My starting list is:

```
contact_list = [["Mike Jordan", 310], ["Jay Z"], ["Oprah Winfrey", 213], ["Leo DeCaprio", 212]]
```

My return dictionary should be:

```py
{
    "Mike Jordan": 310,
    "Jay Z": None,
    "Oprah Winfrey": 213,
    "Leo DeCaprio": 212,    
}
```

I am very new to python (I have used R in the past). I am hoping someone could help me solve this problem. It seems very simple but I am getting stuck at the point where my loop has to handle the empty value.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
none= None

def contacts(contact_list):
  for list in contact_list:
    if len(list) == 2:
      print(list)
    else:
      print(None)
```

But this returns:

```
['Mike Jordan', 310]
None
['Oprah Winfrey', 213]
['Leo DeCaprio', 212]
```

Comment: What is it that you are expecting as output? The program seems to be doing exactly what it's supposed to do. 

P.S.: Avoid using `list` as a name/variable. It's a reserved keyword for the function that creates lists.

Comment: @navneethc. I am trying to get a dictionary, and I want that dictionary to include the names and area codes. Where there is no area code (i.e. "Jay Z") I would like the dictionary to return None. Right now I have only created lists and the Jay Z entry is missing because the area code has no value associated with the name.

Comment: I see a solution to your problem has been posted. That said, here's a good place to learn about how to create, access and modify dictionaries: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'll never have repeated names in your `contact_list`

```py
def contacts(contact_list):
    contact_dict = {}
    for contact in contact_list:
        try:
            contact_dict[contact[0]] = contact[1]
        except IndexError:
            contact_dict[contact[0]] = None
    return contact_dict
```

Comment: **Thank you!** This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem - it is very common in Python to use `try` / `except` over testing (kind of a 'do first, ask questions later') - see [Is it a good practice to use try except else in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python) for more on that. If this answer has helped you, please consider accepting it as the answer (button to the left). Thanks.