# How to check the type of data coming from POST request through API in Flask? Raising an error if incoming data is not is not an Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask, python-imaging-library

I have a portion of code like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
  
   if flask.request.method == 'POST':
           #global mymodel
           first  =datetime.now()
           f = request.files["img"].read()
           f = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f))
```

This code predicts whether an image is Spam or not. I want to `RaiseCustomError` with a messsage **Please upload an image** But for this I need to detect the data type of the incoming `ByteString`. I have thought about using the  `f = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f))` inside a `try` block so when an error occurs, it can perform

```
exception as e:
    return e
```

but that is stupid to do in my own opinion.

How can I detect the type of data from POST request so that if it not something belonging to  any of Image type, I can raise a custom error with a message.

`

Comment: "but that is stupid to do in my own opinion." - Why is that? Using try/except in this case is [very pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16138864/4032503). The accepted answer of using file extensions is extraordinarily naive, especially since you are trying to identify spam. Spoofing a file extension is trivial, especially in the spamming world where they are always trying to get around spam detection schemes.

Comment: NO..you got me wrong. This is supposed to be a Machine Learning Spam. I want to identify my kind of spams and throw an error when there is something else uploaded than image extension.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file extension whether they are in the allowed list. You can customize the list with the image type that you wanna allow. For example,

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ["png", "jpg"]
```

Before reading the image you can check the extension like this way

```
given_file = request.files["img"]
if given_file and allowed_file(given_file.filename):
    # Write your code here
else:
    abort(400, 'File is not a valid image type')
```

Comment: Would ```f_type = f.filename.split('.')[-1]       if not f and f_type in allowed_extensions: abort(400,'message)``` would do?

Comment: You get the logic. You can implement it in any way you want.