# Handling NoSuchElementException To Proceed with Alternative Action

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to decide on whether to use `if` and `else` or `try` and `exception` to handle NoSuchElementException.

I tried using below but it's not working. The NoSuchElementException error appears and the program stops there and doesn't continue to the `else` statement.

```
if len(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order.list_order_list_order_list[1].ref_doc_no']/span"))>0:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order.list_order_list_order_list[1].ref_doc_no']/span").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[7]/a/span").click()
    
else:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='breadcrumb_susBreadCrumb']/a[2]/span").click()
    enter_po_search("3020331278")
```

I used below and it works.

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order.list_order_list_order_list[1].ref_doc_no']/span").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[7]/a/span").click()
    enter_po_search("3020331278")

except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='breadcrumb_susBreadCrumb']/a[2]/span").click()
    enter_po_search("3020331278")
```

Am I doing this right? Is there a better way to code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are still getting error in the first snippet is that you are using `find_element` instread of `find_elements`

so replacing

```
if len(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order.list_order_list_order_list[1].ref_doc_no']/span"))>0:
```

into

```
if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order.list_order_list_order_list[1].ref_doc_no']/span"))>0:
```

will work.

For the style of coding, in Python, it is very common and acceptable to use `try-except` in your logic flow, more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python). So either using `if-else`, or using `try-except` is ok.

Comment: Thanks! No wonder the `if` statement didn't work. Thanks for the reading material too, I appreciate it.