# How do you filter letters and symbols from inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, string, input, integer

I'm a fairly new to python, and I have an assignment to make a random number guesser. I have everything working, but I want to filter out the arguments that break the code, like putting in nothing or letters.

Here's the code.

```
#import random from python libraries
   from random import randint
#generate random integer
   comp_Num = randint(1, 1000)

#creates an infinite loop
    while True:
#allow user to input number int() turns the str into an int
    user_Num = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 1000 \n" ))
#if user number bigger than computer number
    if user_Num > comp_Num:
        print("Too high! Guess again")

else:
    #if user number smaller than computer number 
          if user_Num < comp_Num:
              print("Too low! Guess again")

    #if user number equal to computer number
        if user_Num == comp_Num:
              print("Well done!")
              #end loop
              break
```

Sorry if the questions a bit simple! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to go about this:

1. You prevent the exception. In your case that can be done with the [`.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) string method, which returns `True` if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.
2. You [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) with [try-except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python).

Comment: How do I use try-except on this particular issue?

Comment: The second paragraph of [this link I put in the answer](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) explain it thoroughly, but in a nutshell: you add the `try` around the code that can cause exceptions (here it's the `user_Num` assignment that can cause a ValueError) and then follow it up by `except` where you can print a warning. *If this answered your question don't forget to accept it.

Comment: thanks for the help!