# How to locate a button using selenium and xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have tried many different ways I found online on how to locate this button, but after every try, the function gives me an empty `list`.

I need to locate the button and click it, to scrape different pages. The whole page is dynamicaly loaded and the contents of the second page aren't loaded until you open it, meaning they are not in a DOM until you move to a seccond page. The pages are dynamic as well, meaning there is no change to the url, if you click on different page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Go to the webpage
driver.get('https://is.muni.cz/predmet/?volby=obory:4382@fakulta:1433@obdobi:podzim%202023,jaro%202024@jazyky:eng')


links = []

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

for i in range(1):
    
    website = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

    links += ['https://is.muni.cz' + link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='course_link')]

    button = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="isi-zobacek-vpravo isi-inline"]')
    button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    i += 1

print(links)

driver.quit()
```

This code just returns an error, because the click function doesn't work, because the button has no content. It is an empty `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue - you try to find multiple elements, that will create a `list`, but these do not have a methode to click.

Second issue - your selection, there is no `a` with such a `class` you try to find.

So change your selection to:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class=" pagination-next"]/a')
```

---

Just in case check out [`expliced waits`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and also concepts of [`try / except`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python) and may use a `while loop` to iterate the pages:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the webpage
driver.get('https://is.muni.cz/predmet/?volby=obory:4382@fakulta:1433@obdobi:podzim%202023,jaro%202024@jazyky:eng')

links = []

while True:
    
    website = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

    links.extend(['https://is.muni.cz' + link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='course_link')])
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[@class=" pagination-next"]/a'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break

print(links)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your XPath expression is incorrect. Refer the below screenshot:

[image]

The correct XPath expression is:

```
//li[@class=" pagination-next"]/a
```

2. Second issue: Refer modified below line, it should be `find_element` and not `find_elements`(plural)

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class=" pagination-next"]/a')
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in this code.

1.The `find_elements` method returns a list of elements,even if there is only one matching element. It would help if you used `find_element` instead.

2.You need to ensure the element is present and clickable before clicking it. You can use `WebDriverWait` for this purpose.

3.Your selection is invalid. Please use the correct path: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class=" pagination-next"]/a')`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

 # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()

 # Go to the webpage
 driver.get('https://is.muni.cz/predmet/?volby=obory:4382@fakulta:1433@obdobi:podzim%202023,jaro%202024@jazyky:eng')

 links = []

 # Set an initial wait time
 driver.implicitly_wait(5)

 for i in range(1):
     website = driver.page_source
     soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

     links += ['https://is.muni.cz' + link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='course_link')]

     # Wait for the button to be clickable
     button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="isi-zobacek-vpravo isi-inline"]'))
     )

     button.click()

     # Add a wait to let the content load
     time.sleep(5)
     i += 1

 print(links)
```