# while loop exit after receive error in a try except

Tags: python, while-loop, except

I would like to execute the Python code, but in the event of a timeout error, I want the code to automatically retry after a 60-second delay and continue. However, if another error occurs, such as a permission issue, the code should exit with the corresponding error message. The current code I have below doesn't exit properly and gets stuck in an infinite loop. How can I modify the code to address this issue? Please advise

```
 pause=60
 while True:
   try:
     df=report.next_records()   ##call the function here
   except:
     sleep(pause)
     pause+=60
   else:
     break
```

Comment: That is because of `else` block

Comment: Catch the correct exception: `except TimeOutError` or something. In general, don't catch all exceptions like you do now (with a bare `except`): be specific which exceptions you catch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to use try-except-else in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python)

Comment: why are you increasing the `pause` variable by 60? Do you want that every retry takes 60 seconds more than the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the specific Exception

```
pause=60
while True:
    try:
        df=report.next_records()   ##call the function here
    except TimeoutError: # or whatever error you're catching
        sleep(pause)
        pause+=60
```

Comment: I'd leave off `except Exception: break`, since the OP asks for " the code should exit with the corresponding error message". Better to have any other exception bubble up. Now the loop just stops, without letting a user know why.

Comment: Oh right, edited.

Comment: If the function succeeds, the loop will run forever - is that right?

Comment: Yes, so either the else arm is needed, or just a `break` directly below the `df=...` line.

Comment: You might want to add that any other error bubbles up, to your answer, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help :

```py
import traceback


pause=60

while True:
    try:
        df=report.next_records()
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        sleep(pause)


# and you can add a condition to stop it when some thing happens


import traceback


pause=60

continue_doing = True

while continue_doing:
    try:
        df=report.next_records()

        if df:                          # here put for example your condition
            continue_doing = False

    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        sleep(pause)
        # pause+=60 i think you do not need this because you want to wait the same time as 60s.
```

Comment: OP wants to distinguish between timeout errors and other kinds of error, so using a bare `except` clause probably won't work.